# What is the difference between requests HTTP URLs, (if different operations)?

Tags: networking, network-programming, httpwebrequest

Can I detect from the URL of the request that the operation requested is:-

- Download.
- Registration.
- Streaming.
- Payment.
- Or Other else..?

Somebody told me that request contains these characters :   '?' '=' is for streaming requests.

Comment: I found that the information of : ? = is absolutely wrong :).

Answer (score 1):

Not reliably. You might be able to guess based on common words used in the URLs for different requests, but HTTP specifies none of what you're asking when it comes to URLs.

'?' and '=' are commonly present in a request that has parameters. But that could be anything.

Comment: Thanks, but
Now, I want to Know from the request it's specific operation, I'm using C# console application.. HOW?